# MySQL - How to add index to certain column?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

How do I add index to certain column?

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD INDEX (COLUMN_NAME)
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD KEY (COLUMN_NAME)
```

Which one is correct?
And can somebody explain what are the differences between them?

Comment: No difference at all.

Comment: I am trying to index a column, but the data is really huge. It's been 2 hours, but it is still on processing... Help?

Comment: [`ALTER TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) About the time an index needs to be created and your actual problem (do you want to check what is happening?), post another question, either here or at **[dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)** and don't forget to include all relevant info (`CREATE TABLE`, size of table in rows, what exact statement you gave and is still running, etc.)

Comment: And as a third alternative there is the more common `create index foo on table_name(column_name)` syntax which is used by basically all other DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [MySQL documentation for `alter table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html), you can find:

```
| ADD {INDEX|KEY} [index_name]
        [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_option] ...
```

It's not stated explicitly, but `index` and `key` are synonyms in this context.  There are no differences between them.